# Vue-Laravel 500 (Internal Server Error) while posting

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am trying to create a simple CRUD using Vue and Laravel. I have a route in `web.php`:

```
Route::resource('phonebook','PhonebookController');
```

and in the `Add.vue` file, i am using `axios` to send POST requests:

```
saveData(){
  console.log(this.$data.list);
  axios.post(`phonebook`,this.$data.list)
    .then((response)=> {
      this.close()
    })
    .catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)
}
```

I have tested if this works for `GET` method without any error. But while posting, it shows:

> app.js:1002 POST http://localhost:8000/phonebook 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Do you have a `store` method in your controller?

Comment: yes i have. I have used resource controller. But the main problem is, axios.post() is not hitting the controller. I have used dd() in the controller to check this.

Comment: And when you tried with `get`, I'm assuming you used `axios.get()` and hit your create method?

Comment: yes. get() is working fine.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but if the js is not on the base url, you will need to add a `/` to the axios URI i.e `/phonebook`. If it's on a page with a different URI like `/phonebook` it will make the URI `/phonebook/phonebook`

Comment: You should verify your log file (by default `storage/logs/laravel.log`. It will tell you what is wrong - it could be missing method, typo, not imported namespace or 1000 other reasons.

Comment: Also check csrf for post

Comment: thanks brother. It is working. You save my day. :D

Comment: @TahmidSaim what was the solution you did i am also having the same error

Comment: I just added a slash "/" before "phonebook" route when posting,
 axios.post(`/phonebook`,this.$data.list)

Answer (score 0):

You can check that error by following this Chrome Inspect>>> Network >>> click on redlink >>> now check response You will get actual problem there.

If the problem/error is "Target class controller does not exist" this is the error from laravel as it doesn't support traditional route declaration anymore so for that You can use:

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\PhonebookController;

 Route::get('/users', [PhonebookController::class, 'index']);
 // or
 Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\PhonebookController@index');
```